# Android application not connecting to Wifi ,but works fine in 3G shared through Wifi

Tags: android, xml, wifi, android-manifest

Hi, I am not able to understand why my android application does not work when it accesses the internet through WiFi.  The application is able to work when it uses its own 3G connection.  It doesn't connect to WIFI.  But if I share my 3g connection which i have in my iPhone through WiFi (tethering) the android device can access the server.  I checked the application in various devices, and changed the manifest as follows, still no response.
The code that doesn't connect is a login page.  I followed normal php script,but it not connecting to that script in WiFi,

Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="cs.nott.ac.uk.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/launch"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.qr.RefresherActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.SummaryActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.management.ManagementandReflection" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.qr.QR_MaterialActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.qr.Starting_offActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.qr.DifferentialActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.qr.ThingsActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.qr.InvestigationsActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.qr.RisksActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.qr.TeachingActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.management.SocialActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.management.PsychologicalActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.management.BiologicalActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.management.AssessmentActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.management.ReflectionsActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.management.learningActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.SummaryPatientsActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.FinalSummaryActivity" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ConfirmActivity"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Any error observed from the log with WIFI?

Comment: I get a connection timeout  error immediatlty

Comment: I had the same issue, and couldn't find out what is causing this. I switched to another wifi network, and my application worked fine. You should give it a try, if you have the chance to connect to another router.

Comment: I've faced possibly similar issue, but it wasn't stable and was related to wifi router configuration. Have You tried rest router / access the same url via phone browser / set timeout for connection (using HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout and HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout)?

Comment: Yes connection timeout was given to 500000ms...not connecting to WiFi at all,even in 3 g dome networks doesn't work especially the login of the application when it reads a php script in remote server

Comment: Can you show us the code that you use to connect from your application to your login page?

Comment: Can you access that service from a PC connected via the same wifi network?  It sounds like a problem with the network configuration,  especially DNS.

Comment: While probably not related to your issue, I do see some other potential issues with your manifest: First, the package name is backwards; it should be written as `uk.ac.nott.cs.app`. Second, your uses-feature should probably include `android:required="false"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was solved by creating a new thread for authentication,This is necessary for the application to work on or above 4.0

Comment: Hi, I'm also facing this problem...i'm using asynctask for authentication..Is that enough for authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Ipv6 router setting. Switch to ipv4 to verify