# Android app not working over wifi, works fine with mobile data connection

Tags: android

I am developing an android app that uses youtube's api for fetching the rtsp url. It works fine on my cell over 3g but doesnt work when connected to wifi. Have this link that suggests the answer, but i dont know how to implement authentication in another thread.

[Android application not connecting to Wifi ,but works fine in 3G shared through Wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292751/android-application-not-connecting-to-wifi-but-works-fine-in-3g-shared-through)"

Comment: This is the same link i have provided in my question too. There is a resolution too but i dont know how to implement that. Need help in that regard. i.e  creating a new thread for authentication

Answer (score 0):

With Http connections on Android, those cannot be done on the Main UI Thread. These sorts of tasks must be done via `Thread` or `AsyncTask`

Comment: Thanks for answering, i am doing it that way only in a new asynctask.. but how to do that authorisation..thats my concern now

Comment: How to create a new thread for authorization, or how to do the authorization itself?

Comment: How to do authorization